# ElasticSearch weird relevancy factors

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I don't understand how come the -0.68 values turns into 0.13. It's supposed to give the maximum value of the elements of array, shouldn't it?

Is this anything with query norms? Can I override this behavior? My relevancy function needs to use these values consistently

```
{
              "value": 0.13904124,
              "description": "function score, score mode [max]",
              "details": [
                {
                  "value": -0.6875923,
                  "description": "function score, product of:",
                  "details": [
                    {
                      "value": 1,
                      "description": "match filter: brand:brandy",
                      "details": []
                    },
                    {
                      "value": -0.6875923,
                      "description": """
script score function, computed with script:"Script{type=inline, lang='painless', idOrCode='new java.util.Random().nextGaussian()', options={}, params={}}" and parameters: 
{}
""",
                      "details": [
                        {
                          "value": 1,
                          "description": "_score: ",
                          "details": [
                            {
                              "value": 1,
                              "description": "id:[59974 TO 59974]",
                              "details": []
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer,
My script randomly assigned different values for the _score value, and the explanation of the score.

The solution is to use some seed value related to the document.